# multiplicities of the roots of a polynom

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose a complex polynom $f$ of the degree $n$ has $k$ multiple roots, and, respectively, $n-l$ simple roots, where $l=\mu_1+\mu_2+\ldots+\mu_k$ is the sum of the multiplicities of the degenerate roots. suppose the roots of the polynomial $f$ are known (were found), and are equal to $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots \lambda_i, \ldots$ does anyone in the forum know an algorithm to find a multiplicity of any root (degenerate, and simple) ? is it possible to express the multiplicity of any root (multiple, and simple) via $f(z)$, $f'(z)$, and $gcd(f,f')$ ? I am asking such questions because in reality there are many problems where a degree of the complex polynomial $f(z)$ is large (hundreds, thousands ...), and it is difficult to control-calculate the multiplicities of each root by hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A root $\lambda$ of polynomial $f(z)$ has multiplicity $\mu \gt 1$ iff $f'(\lambda)=f''(\lambda)=\cdots=f^{(\mu-1)}(\lambda)=0\,$ and $f^{(\mu)}(\lambda)\ne 0$. It follows that $\lambda$ is then a root of $\gcd(f, f', \cdots , f^{(\mu-1)})$.

In other words, a root $\lambda$ is simple iff $f'(\lambda) \ne 0\,$, and has a multiplicity $\mu \gt 1$ if the first $\mu-1$ derivatives of $f$ vanish at $\lambda$ but $f^{\mu}$ does not.

Since you know the roots already, determining the multiplicity amounts to finding the lowest order derivative which does *not* vanish at the given value or, equivalently, the smallest $\mu$ such that $g_\mu = \gcd(f, f', \cdots, f^\mu)$ is non-zero at the given value. This can be tricky in numerical calculations with limited precision.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful that would be in an algorithm, but I'm sure it could be interesting.

Let $r$ be the number of **different roots** of your polynomial, and $\mu_i$ the order of multiplicity (possibly 1) of $\lambda_i$ the $i$-th root. We have :

$$f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}(X - \lambda_i)^{\mu_i}$$
and :
$$f'(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^{r}\mu_i\lambda_i(X - \lambda_i)^{\mu_i - 1}\prod_{j = 1, \neq i}^{r}(X - \lambda_j)^{\mu_j}$$

Thus you have :

$$(\frac{f'}{f})(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{\mu_i\lambda_i}{X - \lambda_i}$$

Since you know every $\lambda_i$, I'm guessing a bit of computation should get you $\mu_i$.